# Designing an audio amplifier with push-pull output stage

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, audio, push-pull

I'm working on a push-pull stage audio amplifier. I'd like your opinion on whether I'm on the right track with this, both theoretically and practically.

In this circuit I'll be using the following components:

Q1&Q2 TIP31C & TIP32C with LM358N op-amp (this was the only available at my university.)

My circuit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to point out that you are asking opinions and have no specific question about the circuit. We also don't know what specifications you require from the amplifier, so it will be impossible to say if you are on the right track or not. You might want to explain why each part is there before someone asks why R1, C2 or C6 are in the circuit.

Comment: Sabretooth, you can do all that with a single rail. Do you already have a dual rail supply you want used? Or would a single supply be cheaper and easier?

Comment: The steady-state power dissipation on Q2 & Q3 is near 3 W, which is a "little" too high. If R7 & R8 are 5 k, it should be 200 mW.

Comment: NB: the voltage on 8 Ohm load without distortion (with  R7=R8=1 kOhm) would be 10 V peak to peak... EE&O.

Comment: Changing Q2-Q3 to Darlington BD675-BD676 --> voltage on 8 Ohm load without distortion (with R7=R8=1 kOhm) would be 20 V peak to peak

Comment: In the audio circuits I have seen, it is not normal to AC couple the voltage gain stage to the output stage. Usually feedback is taken from the output and fed all the way back to the input stage to maintain DC output level. But I am not an audio expert.

Comment: And if this is school work, we are basically doing homework here, if the task is to research how to improve a simple audio amplifier.

Comment: C6 is rather low in value and will roll off your output below 200 Hz, if you're not only interested in 6 kHz signals. But why is it there at all? You have a bipolar supply so why not get rid of it and DC couple the output? Running feedback around the entire circuit, as suggested by Andy aka, will help to minimise the DC offset on the output.

Comment: One last time. Sabertooth... what power requrirements do you have for the speaker (maximum, I mean?) And again, do you feel you need +/- 15 V rails? Or could you consider a single +30 V rail (or less?)

Comment: @Justme apologize for the late reply, I wanted to know if this circuit is good enough to have low distortion for the audio but I realized it still not good enough so I am beginning from scratch again

Comment: @jonk apologize for the late reply, I believe dual DC source would be more efficient with single source that is why I am going for dual

Comment: @Antonio51 apologize for the late reply, yes I realized that yesterday that is why I am starting form scratch again

Comment: @mkeith apologize for the late reply, I believe so I'll be starting from scratch again

Comment: Maybe try reading some of Douglas Self's books or online writings on audio.

Comment: @Justme although it is is school work our task is to create one from scratch. I just wanted opinion if my design is efficient (generally) or not

Comment: @GrahamNye True, I realized this design is not efficient enough and have huge distortion, I'll start from scratch again.

Comment: @jonk No power requirement, actually there is no requirement at all. it is like design what you want at the end of the day it should have audible audio without or less distortion

Comment: @mkeith yes, I'll do that, thank you for the reference.

Comment: @Sabretooth2438 I understand but strictly asking for opinions is off-topic. Since it is school work it is you who should do the research and maybe then ask an answerable question about it. Also, what do you mean by "efficient"? If you want efficient you would simply buy a D-class amplifier chip or design a D-class circuit, but likely that is not the point of the assignment if you are building a linear AB class amplifier.

Comment: @Justme I am making class B, but I understand

Comment: Updated the circuit

Comment: @Sabretooth2438 Now you changed the question and are asking if it will produce distortion, so it invalidated many comments and answers. Yes, it will produce distortion. How much is another question. But you have a simulator so you can see how much in the simulator.

Comment: @Justme it gives me sinusoidal wave as seen in the picture

Comment: @Sabretooth2438 - Hi, You cannot now make major changes to *this* question, after receiving answers which answered your previous version and which would be made invalid by this change (as just commented). Therefore I have rolled-back the latest edit. I recommend you consider [accepting an answer](/help/someone-answers) to the version of the schematic with the op-amp, or (if none is, in your judgement, a full answer to that) at least comment that *this* question is over. Then ask a clear new question, link back to this one, explain what you learned *here* & why the new question is different. TY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This modified circuit will have "better" performance due to negative feedback via R2 connected directly to the output and, dc coupling the op-amp to the power-transistor stage: -

[image]

The above modifications are pretty much what most class AB audio amplifiers use.

> *I'd like your opinion on whether I'm on the right track with this*

In my opinion, you are not really going places with your design. I mean it will work but, it will have higher distortion than mine (due to the way I've implemented negative feedback) and, if you improved the op-amp type (higher speed and slew rate) mine would be even better whereas your design wouldn't improve with a better op-amp.

Comment: apologize for the late reply, yes, I'll be starting from scratch

Answer (score 1):

D1 and D2 on your circuit set up the idle current. This is a poor match to V<sub>be</sub>. Put a [rubber diode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_diode) which is sometimes called a VBE multiplier in place of the 1N4001 pair. Place the rubber diode connected transistor in good thermal contact with the output transistors, like on a common heatsink.

Comment: I'd like to mention that "rubber diode" simply means a Vbe multiplier, which is far more common term for it.

Comment: @Autistic we don't have that available at the Uni

Comment: @sabretooth2438 .You can make your own rubberdiode with say a TIP31 and try 2 say 1 K resistors .

Comment: Can I make it with any other transistor? Since we have limited amount for each student

Comment: @sabertooth2438  yes you can use a different transistor.Do measure your idle current and adjust if needed.